# pyenv: fab: command not found

Tags: python, fabric, pyenv

Few days ago MacOS removed Python2. So I installed it with pyenv but fab is not working.

Config in .zshrc:

```sh
...
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

alias python="$(pyenv which python)"
alias pip="$(pyenv which pip)"
```

I've created virtualenv with `pyenv virtualenv 2.7.18 myenv`. Activated it with `pyenv activate myenv` and also tried `pyenv local myenv`, `pyenv local myenv 2.7.18` and bunch of other similar commands.

I also checked if fabric is installed with

```sh
$ pip freeze 

... 
Fabric==1.14.0
...
```

```sh
$ fab start                                                                                                                                                          
pyenv: fab: command not found

The `fab' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.18

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

How do I use fab commands with pyenv?

Answer (score 0):

as for me I use my own Shell script named `fab` as:

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT_PATH=`readlink -f $0`
SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname "$SCRIPT_PATH"`

if [ ! -d "$SCRIPT_DIR/_venv" ]; then
    python3 -m venv "$SCRIPT_DIR/_venv"
    "$SCRIPT_DIR"/_venv/bin/pip install -r "$SCRIPT_DIR"/requirements.txt
fi

"$SCRIPT_DIR"/_venv/bin/fab $*
```